# How to set fqdn of the local machine in knife.rb

Tags: chef-infra

This is my knife.rb file. In this I want to set the node_name as fqdn of that local machine. I dont want to manually type it.
 Because I have to use this for n number of machines. I just write the default attribute to get the fqdn of the machine.
 
It gives ruby **syntax error**.

```
log_level                :info

log_location             STDOUT

client_key               '/etc/chef/client.pem'

node_name                '#node['fqdn']'

chef_server_url          'myserverurl'


SyntaxError: /root/.chef/knife.rb:5: syntax error, 
unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
node_name                '#node['fqdn']'
                                     ^
```

Relevant file content:

```
  4: client_key               '/etc/chef/client.pem'

  5: node_name                '#node['fqdn']'

  6: chef_server_url          'myserverurl'
```

Comment: instead of '#node['fqdn']' also try with <%=node['fqdn'] %> It also show same syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Tensibai and coderanger that this isn't your best approach, but if you really want to do it, then I'd suggest you reach out the machine and ask.

```
node_name `hostname --fqdn`
```

OR

```
node_name `hostname`
```

depending on whether you want the fqdn or not.  Both, of course, assume you have a valid hostname set on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Node attributes are a Chef recipe thing, they don't exist for the config (on top of generally invalid Ruby syntax). Fortunately for you, the FQDN is already the default node_name so just don't specify one at all!

Comment: If I don't specify the node name then it shows error to assign the node name. How to make it work this knife.rb file

Answer (score 0):

As per comment:

Generate the knife.rb file with chef if you really want it.

Use a template resource in a cookbook which will generate the knife.rb from an .erb file where you'll include `<%= node['fqdn'] %>` as coderanger said.

But I highly advise not doing so because your provisionning system should already handle the destruction/recreation of a node, so it's more the place where to manage the node and client in chef rather than the node itself.

Old:

Why would you like to use Knife on all your nodes ?

Knife is an administration tool supposed to be used on workstations to manage nodes, cookbboks etc.

Please explain your use case, so we can edit and guide you on what you try to achieve. It's an XY Problem there (question on a tool instead of question on the problem)

Comment: Actually I want to delete my node from that node itself. So that I write this knife.rb file. If I put my fqdn in that node_name it works fine. But for n nodes how can I achieve this?

Comment: Edited answer for your us case even if I think it's a conception error having a node deleting itself.

Comment: knife node delete -y $(hostname -f). this work fine when I executing from that node itself, only I set the fqdn of that machine

Comment: @VijayVishnu It is not that it works fine, just that this is not the place to manage it. How would you do it if your node crash at a point it turns unbootable anymore ? You're just going toward pitfalls. Manage your infrastructure from a referential somewhere (could be anything) and do the work to be able to delete or redo a node at any time independently of this node state (running, powered off, crashed and irrecuperable, etc.).